# Geospatial data set for monthly averaged wind speed or power density

Tags: geospatial, weather, climate, open-source

I want to evaluate seasonal variability of wind turbines (in combination with a Power to X plant). Ideally, wind turbines would create a constant seasonal power output to supply the continuous demand of PtX process, which would reduce the need and size for electricity and hydrogen storage.

For this I am looking for a geospatial data set that provides monthly averaged wind speed oder wind power density, ideally at a global scale. Specifically I am looking for data sets in Spain and Australia.

The [Global Wind Atlas](https://globalwindatlas.info/en/download/gis-files) only offers yearly averaged wind speed and power density data.

Similarly, the [Global Solar Atlas](https://globalsolaratlas.info/map) offers monthly averaged Global horizontal irradiation GeoTIFF files (e.g. [Global Solar Atlas for Australia under LTAym_YearlyMonthlyTotals](https://globalsolaratlas.info/download/australia)). That is what I need just for wind.